# Select a rows with a one-to-many relationship with another table, but also include rows that have no existing relationship to the table

Tags: mysql, sql

I am working with a database that contains a table `Schedule`.

```
schedule_id | taf_id | active | start_date | end_date
     1      |   -1   |   1    |"2017-08-27"|"2017-09-01"
     2      |   23   |   1    |"2018-01-01"|"2018-01-05"
     3      |   134  |   1    |"2018-01-03"|"2018-02-01"
```

If a row in the Schedule table has a corresponding row in the TAF table then the value of the `taf_id` field will not be -1.
Rows in the TAF table will always have a corresponding row in the Revision table. And rows in the Revision table will always have 3 corresponding rows in the Booking table.

All this data used to be acquired by first selecting all active schedule rows for an employee that fell between two given dates and then making a separate database query for each row in Schedule that had a taf_id greater than -1. However, the overhead of all those calls is too much.

In order to speed this call up I wanted to grab all the information at once with this call:

```
SELECT * FROM Schedule
    LEFT JOIN TAF ON TAF.taf_id=Schedule.taf_id
    LEFT JOIN Revision ON Revision.revision_id=TAF.revision_id
    RIGHT JOIN Booking ON Booking.revision_id=Revision.revision_id
WHERE Schedule.employee_id=<EMPLOYEES_ID>
    AND Schedule.active
    AND Schedule.start_date<=<END_DATE> AND Schedule.end_date>=<START_DATE>
ORDER BY Schedule.start_date;
```

This call returns three rows for every selected `Schedule` row, but the redundant data can just be ignored. However, now I can not get any rows from the `Schedule` table that have a `taf_id` field that equals -1. I know the LEFT JOIN's will just give me null fields, so it must be the RIGHT JOIN command that excludes these Schedule rows.

Is there a way to use the RIGHT JOIN command to include rows that have nothing to join onto, or am I going about this in the wrong way? Is there some other way to query for a one-to-many relationship where "many" may be nothing?

Here is a link to a mock version of the database: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d925be/14

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  Also, using `NULL` for a non-match makes more sense to me than `-1`.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Never thought I'd praise `NULL`. But I agree 100%

Comment: That `RIGHT JOIN` isn't joining to your `Schedule` table at all. It's joining to `Revision`. It shouldn't reduce results from `Schedule`, but it may reduce results from `Revision`.

Comment: Sample data and expectations would definitely help. Using http://sqlfiddle.com/ works great for that kind of thing, and then update your question.

Comment: @Shawn . . . Ironically, I am working now on a database with a dimensional model.  We do use something like 0 or -1 for missing data -- but there is a corresponding row in the dimension table.  We want to be sure that all rows match.